# Inserting rows from one table to another another with PK column value incrementing in MS Access Database

Tags: ms-access-2007, rownum

We have two tables,table1(id int,name nvarchar(50)) and table2(id int,name nvarchar(50)). For both tables id is primary key.I want to move rows from table2 to table1 with PK value incrementing i.e i want id=max(id)+1 of table1 for all rows copying .I found this query like this for sql server

```
declare @root int 
select @root=max(id) from Bgd_common.dbo.table1 
insert into Bgd_common.dbo.table1(id,Name) select @root + ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY ID),name from Bgd_common.dbo.table2
```

But ROW_NUMBER() will not work with Acces database.I don't want to use built in Auto increment property because I want to delete a row and then insert row in middle etc and Built in Auto increment property will cause some restriction on operations.How can i do same thing in MS access??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used Dcount in place of Row Number() and it worked!
Here is final query

```
insert into Bgd_common.dbo.table1(id,Name) select (select max(id) from Bgd_common.dbo.table1) + Dcount("id","test2","id <= " & [id]) ,name from Bgd_common.dbo.table2
```

Answer (score 1):

here is the link that would solve your problem
http://www.vb123.com/toolshed/07_access/countercolumn.htm

Answer (score 0):

Is table1 ID an autonumber? If it is, you can simply copy table2 `[name]` to table1 and the values will increment. If it is not an autonumber, it may be best to make it one. MS Access works very well with autonumber IDs.

Comment: I don't want to use built in autonumber property because it will cause some restriction on operations